# always keep checked at least one checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have three `Checkbox` widgets and I want one of them to always be selected. How can I implement it in Flutter using the `Checkbox` widget?

I have tried using `GroupedButtons` plugin but I wasn't able to put the text right after the `checkbox` like a line even if they had a horizontal option, so I want to use the `Checkbox` Widget.

```
Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Row(
                   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Checkbox(
                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                          value: arbi,
                          onChanged:(bool changed){
                        setState(() {
                          arbi = changed;
                        });
                          }
                      ),
                      Text("arbi"),
                      Checkbox(value: banglauccharon,
                          activeColor: Colors.green,
                          onChanged:(bool changed){
                            setState(() {
                              banglauccharon = changed;
                            });
                          }
                      ),
                      Text("bangla"),
                      Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
                        child: Checkbox(value: bagnlameann,
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            onChanged:(bool changed){
                              setState(() {
                                bagnlameann = changed;
                              });
                            }
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("bangla",style: ,)
                    ],
                  )
              ),
```

Comment: why do you need to use checkbox? what u're asking can be accomplished with Radio() widget

Comment: But in Radio i can  only choose one item.. i want user to choose as many he want but even if he don't want he need to choose one..i hope u understand what i am trying to explain

Comment: What  pedro pimont said  is true , use  Radio() widget   , You only need to choose any option , like  'banglauccharon' and add init state  'true' in 'initState()' method

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

In this case I made so that `arbi` checkbox would be checked if none was.

```
         Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Checkbox(
                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                      value: arbi || banglauccharon || bagnlameann ? arbi : true,
                      onChanged:(bool changed){
                    setState(() {
                      arbi = changed;
                    });
                      }
                  ),
                  Text("arbi"),
                  Checkbox(value: banglauccharon,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                      onChanged:(bool changed){
                        setState(() {
                          banglauccharon = changed;
                        });
                      }
                  ),
                  Text("bangla"),
                  Theme(
                    data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
                    child: Checkbox(value: bagnlameann,
                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                        onChanged:(bool changed){
                          setState(() {
                            bagnlameann = changed;
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("bangla")
                ],
              )
          );
```

Comment: this worked but a weird thing happens each tiime i uncheck everyone of them it does auto check the arbi checkbox.. but even if it's true it doesn't show the data it was suppose to show while it's true

Comment: have you tried toggle buttons in flutter? it can be applied to this requirement